# mysqldump export only help and opions

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to export databases and I can not see my sql code it only shows the help in the file.sql:

```
Usage: mysqldump [OPTIONS] database [tables] OR mysqldump [OPTIONS] --databases [OPTIONS] DB1 [DB2 DB3....] OR mysqldump [OPTIONS] --all-databases [OPTIONS] For more options, use mysqldump --help
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should run it like this

`mysqldump -u [REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_DB_USER] -p [REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_DB_NAME] > output.sql`

for example

`mysqldump -u root -p mydatabase > output.sql`

Remove the brackets around it is just for showing that these are placeholders

run this it will ask for password, enter the password and then you will have your database script in output.sql file.

This is the case if you are running this command on the same system where the mysql is running.

Comment: I did this: "mysqldump -u root -p mydb > output.sql"  in my debian virtual machine, so the file created it doesn't have the SQL code as it should be, I only get mysqldump help about how to use it instead.

Comment: Ok can you please share the screenshot of the command that you are running and also file that you get.